# How to use awk and read together in bash script?

Tags: bash, awk

```
var1='"name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name": "Mary"'

$var1 | tr -d '",' | awk '{print $2}'
```

The above code gives o/p:

```
John
Ron
Mary
```

Now I want to read each of the above names and use it in some other command. For eg :

```
$var1 | tr -d '",' | awk '{print $2}' | { read -r student_name; ./redis-cli -c -h <redis hostname> -p 9443 hmset school:student:student_name rollno $roll_no; }
```

How can I get to read each of the names and pass them to the above shown redis command? 
The above bash script only takes the first name which is "John" and passes it to the redis command. After passing "John", I also want it to pass the next student name to redis and so on.

For this example, I have used only 3 names, but there could be hundreds of them. Everything needs to be done in a single line script.

Comment: `$var1 | tr -d '",'` is a syntax error, what does your real code look like? What you've shown tries to run `name : John` etc. as a command.

Comment: Are you sure???? Maybe you mean ```echo $var1 | ...``` ? Also, if I change your "it works code" to include an echo, it only produces a : character. It certainly doesn't look like it is even close to producing your stated actual output. Please refer to
[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Don't forget that there is also a difference between `var1=""name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name" : "Mary""` and `var2='"name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name" : "Mary"'. While `echo "$var1"` returns `name : John, name : Ron, name : Mary`, the command `echo "$var2"` returns `"name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name" : "Mary"`. The latter is most likely what the OP was attempting. You can see this as the OP tries to use `tr -d '","'` which seems like he wants to remove the combination `",` but `tr` actually interprets it as removing `"` and `","

Answer (score 2):

Why use `read` at all, when you have `awk`.
If this is the input (added space before last `:`)

```
var1=""name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name" : "Mary""
```

The you can do this:

```
echo $var1 | awk -F: '{print "Hello" $2}' RS=,
Hello John
Hello Ron
Hello Mary
```

This sets record selector to `,` and field separator to `:` and then print every record with `hello` before it.

---

If data on the other hand is:

```
var1='"name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name" : "Mary"'
echo $var1
"name" : "John", "name" : "Ron", "name" : "Mary"
```

Then you should do:

```
echo $var1 | awk -F: '{split($2,a,"\"");print "Hello",a[2]}' RS=,
Hello John
Hello Ron
Hello Mary
```